# Hide ol with css

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to hide the content of an OL that appears randomly on this test site (see red square): http://m.theseolounge.co.uk/[image: screenshot]

I have tried this but it is still displaying it and I do not understand why it only happens with Chrome.

```
#control-nav li{
 display:none;
 }
```

Comment: I see `.control-nav` not `#control-nav` being used.

Comment: The problem doesn't show on my end as shown in the picture.

Comment: I tried .control-nav but does not work either. @jerseyetr are you trying with chrome?

Comment: `.control-nav li { display: none; }` works for me in Chrome.

Comment: @RobertoBertuol Yes, im using chrome. Everything looks normal on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is reproduced in Chromium, the Linux version of Chrome I am using. Oddly, about a minute after the page opens, the list numbers disappear. When I switch tabs and switch back right away, the {ol} element is there and then disappears in about 1 second. When I looked in the inspector, it told me the {ol} element is inheriting {display:block} from {div.page}.